# Do spark.implicits exist for pyspark session?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am asking perhaps a dumb question. Nevertheless:

> Do `spark.implicits._` exists for pyspark session and if so how do I import them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://spark.apache.org/docs/preview/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/session.html), you cannot.

This probably comes from the fact that [spark.implicits._](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala) uses the implicit type def in scala, which is a concept that do not exist in python.